# Azure Devops - for ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

While Running a job for arm template deployment using a Power shell script it's throwing error like the term New-AzumResourceGroupDeployment is not recognized as a name of cmdlet function script file.can anyone help me understand on this.

Comment: Does your agent have Azure RM PowerShell installed?

Comment: What's the result after you trying it?

Answer (score 0):

Odds are the AzureRM Powershell module isn't installed on the machine.  Run the following command in an elevated powershell session: [More Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber
```

I would make a recommendation note to user AzureRm as it has been replaced with the Az  module.  For Az run: [More Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.8.0) If the machine has Az already installed on it then skip to the alias section as this would also throw the error you are describing if Az is installed and the script is reference Rm

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber
```

If you are running powershell that reference the AzureRm module create an alias for it after installing Az by running

```
Enable-AzureRmAlias -Scope CurrentUser
```

After the installing the Az Module

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2/README.md) that could be used to deploy ARM template.

Also, there is [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) that would include many modules, so you can use this task too.

Secondly, the command is New-AzureRmResourcegroupdeployment or New-AzResourceGroupDeployment.

On the other hand, by default, for powershell task, it won't include Azure Modules, you need to install or import it. Check DreadedFrost's reply.

Related article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0